# Bootstrap dropup not working on firefox but works perfectly fine on google chrome

Tags: html, css, firefox, button

Basically I have a fixed dropup at the bottom of the page that is used for changing the language. It works perfectly on chrome but on Firefox it doesn't work.

If you want to see the results for yourself visit burnxfreeze.netlify.com on chrome and Firefox and you'll see what I mean.

I think I have put in all the relevant code. But just in case, for the full code view source on the web page.

Thanks and I appreciate your help

--HTML--

```
<head>

    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">



</head>

<body>

<section>


<ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">

    <!-- Defines a primary dropdown -->
    <li class="nav-item dropup"> <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="langbtn" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" style="position:fixed; z-index:99; bottom: 2%; left: 2%; border: 2px solid black !important; background: yellow !important; color: black !important; "> <img id="lang-img" src="non-html/images/langbtn/lang-icon.png" style="width:20px; height:20px;" />  </a>

        <!-- Defines the list containing the primary dropdown links -->
        <ul class="dropdown-menu scrollable-menu" id="langlist" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">

            <!-- Defines the primary dropdown items -->
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Arabic</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Chinese</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">English</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">French</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">German</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Greek</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Hebrew</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Hindi</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Italian</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Japanese</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Kurdish</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Latin</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Polish</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Portuguese</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Punjabi</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Russian</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Somali</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Spanish</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Turkish</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Urdu</a></li>

        </ul>
    </li>
</section>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" ></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" ></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>

</body>
```

--CSS--

```
.scrollable-menu {
    height:auto;
    max-height: 150px;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 2px !important;
}

.dropup li {
    border: 2px solid #FF8C00;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: grey !important;
    z-index: 99;
    margin: 2px 0 2px 0;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.dropup li .dropdown-item {
    color: black !important;
}
```

Comment: You have a `ul` that is not closed, first element inside the `section`.

Comment: Thanks. That is helpful. However it still doesn't work on Firefox. Is Firefox not compatible with bootstrap 4?

Comment: It is compatible.

Comment: that's good. but i just don't get why only the dropup doesn't work. dropdowns work perfectly. any ideas?